# button click to switch activity to a randomn from a list of activity

Tags: android

I just want on button click to switch to a different activity from a possible list of activities, like say activity1, activity2 and so on. And for some reason my current method won't allow me to use more than 2 and now the (rand<0.5) is giving some kind of rand double error aswell.

```
reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Random rand = new Random();
        if (rand <0.5) {
               Intent reset1 = new Intent(Title.this, MainActivity.class);
               startActivity(reset1);
           } else {
               Intent reset2 = new Intent(Title.this, Question36.class);
               startActivity(reset2); 
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: what type of error you get..?

Comment: I think that you want to develop  a basic quiz app, doesn't you ? If your answer is yes, check this https://github.com/gitssk/quizfun

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);

 if(randomInt <50){
                           Intent reset1 = new Intent(Title.this, MainActivity.class);
                           startActivity(reset1);
                       } else {
                           Intent reset2 = new Intent(Title.this, Question36.class);
                           startActivity(reset2); 
                    }
```

Comment: eclipse.buildId=v21.0.1-543035
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

Warning
Wed Aug 14 14:50:21 AST 2013
The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

Comment: this is the last error ... but i dont think it comes when running .. however the log cat has many errors when i try to run the app

Comment: Did you debug your code, are you sure that problem is you posted in this topic ?

Answer (score 0):

make the changes in the AndroidManifest file.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.alphabets.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >

<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>

<activity
    android:name="com.example.alphabets.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

try it

Comment: i will a little more detail please

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have 5 activites then

```
   reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.First_btnNext);
    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                 Random rand = new Random();
                 int num=rand.nextInt(5);

                 switch (num) {
            case 0:
                     Intent reset0 = new Intent(Title.this, FirstActivity.class);
                     startActivity(reset0);
                break;
            case 1:
                     Intent reset1 = new Intent(Title.this, SecondActivity.class);
                     startActivity(reset1);
                break;
            case 2:
                    Intent reset2 = new Intent(Title.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                    startActivity(reset2);
                break;
            case 3:
                    Intent reset3 = new Intent(Title.this, FourthActivity.class);
                    startActivity(reset3);
               break;
            case 4:
                    Intent reset4 = new Intent(Title.this, FifthActivity.class);
                    startActivity(reset4);
               break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
   });
```

Comment: could you please insert one of my intent in one of your case .. because i cant figure out the correct arrangement ....

Comment: i tried it .. replaced my own activities into it and still the app crashes when i press the button .. error log shows no new errors ... but the log cat goes crazy .. any idea .. iam stuck

Comment: then without logcat it's difficult to say anything.